# Java buffer strategy sometimes doesn't draw properly

Tags: java, bufferstrategy

I created a game in Java which uses buffer strategy. But sometimes I just get a white frame or a white border. That happens about every fifth time. I searched a lot but I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The code compiles and there aren't any errors printed out.

If if fails, the frame looks for example like that:

[white border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UUHg.png)

[completely white frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bQ2n.png)

Here's code (only the relevant parts):

```
private BufferStrategy bs;
public Testclass(){
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(1000,600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    setVisible(true);
    createBufferStrategy(2);
    bs = getBufferStrategy();
}

protected void paint() {
    do {
        Graphics2D g=null;
        try {
            g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        } finally {
            g.dispose();
        }
        bs.show();
    } while (bs.contentsLost());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Testclass window = new Testclass();
    window.paint();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else going on outside of the code you provided?  I dumped it into my sandbox, and I can't get it to reproduce the problem.  I always get a window displaying only blue.  No white border or anything.

Comment: I have just this class. I tested it with Eclipse an I manually compiled it and in both cases it fails sometimes. My operating system is Ubuntu, but I think think that shouldn't matter.

Comment: The operating system always matters when using Java Swing.  Swing behavior is different on different operating systems and different Java versions.

Comment: I'm on Windows, using Intellij.  There could be configuration differences :(

Comment: I just tried it on a Windows 10 an it works there. So probably this problem is operating system specific. But I think it's strange that the program works sometimes on Linux and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a better way try this:

```
   boolean BufferStrategyRunning = true;

    while(BufferStrategyRunning == true) {

        BufferStrategy BS = GUIFrame.getBufferStrategy();

        if(BS == null) {
        GUIFrame.createBufferStrategy(3);
        continue;
        }

        Graphics g = BS.getDrawGraphics();

        g.drawImage(CurrentScreen.BackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        BS.show();


    }
```

Comment: This allows it to have enough time to create the buffer strategy if you look inside the java code there is a sepreate thread created to make the bufferstrategy that will run slower then your application code that is why sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.

Comment: That is why other people are not having the same issue because they have a beast of computer that can calculate the cure for cancer are computers can hardly calculate the radius of a potato.